# Angular 11 - Add icons with different styles to a custom button component

Tags: javascript, css, angular

In my Angular 11 App I've implemented a custom button component.
For styling I use TailwindCSS and TailwindUI.

The button can have multiple colors(`red`, `blue`, `gray`, etc) and also different sizes (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`).

I want to create a variant for these buttons: a button with a leading icon, as shown here:
https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/elements/buttons#component-8a4b7248253ad4c9ee892c655d7ff5ec.

For the icons, I use the following library:
https://ng-heroicons.dimaslz.dev/

An icon is a component, like: `<mail-solid-icon></mail-solid-icon>`, `<bookmark-solid-icon></bookmark-solid-icon>` etc.

Because of the different sizes (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`) of the button, I need to add custom Tailwind classes to the icon. For example:

```
<app-button [size]="'xs'">
  <mail-solid-iconclass="-ml-0.5 mr-2" [size]="16"></mail-solid-icon>
  Button text
</app-button>

<app-button [size]="'xl'">
  <bookmark-solid-icon class="-ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5" [size]="20"></bookmark-solid-icon>
Button text
```

**Desired result:**

I want to be able to provide only the icon component and then, *in button's component class*, to add the classes `-ml-0.5 mr-2`, or `-ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5`; as well as the `size` property.

Example of use in a template:

```
 <app-button [size]="'xl'">
  <bookmark-solid-icon></bookmark-solid-icon>
   Button text
 </app-button>
```

Output:

```
<app-button [size]="'xl'">
  <bookmark-solid-icon class="-ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5" [size]="20"></bookmark-solid-icon>
   Button text
 </app-button>
```

I've tried to use a custom directive and get it using `@ContentChild`, but I can't add the classes to it.

Thanks!

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6gpcby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sample code that may help you to achieve what you want to do: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xymefd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.ts

What I changed from your code are:

1. Add `ButtonIconDirective` to AppModule declarations.
2. Use `appButtonIcon` instead of `docsButtonIcon`.
3. Inject `ElementRef` into `ButtonIconDirective`. (We will use ElementRef in `ButtonComponent`).
4. Append a template variable onto `<bookmark-solid-icon>` to get its component instance.
5. Rewrite `ngAfterContentInit` in `ButtonComponent` method to update `size` and add new CSS classes at runtime:

```js
public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  console.log( 'this.icon: ', !!this.icon);
  
  if (this.icon) {

    // reference to ng-heroicons component source code
    this.icon.style = '';
    this.icon.size = 50;     
    this.icon.renderStyle(); 

    this.renderer.addClass(this.iconi.er.nativeElement, '-ml-1');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.iconi.er.nativeElement, 'mr-3');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.iconi.er.nativeElement, 'h-5');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.iconi.er.nativeElement, 'w-5');      

    console.log(this.icon.style);
  }
}
```